# Advice needed regarding whether or not to withdraw a DSA course

Tags: graduate-admissions

I am enrolled in a Data Structures and Algorithms course and am doing my B.Tech in India. Now, in this course I am currently below average and am expecting a 7/10 overall grade. However, if I withdraw the course and put in some effort next semester, I am sure I can get a 8 or 9. Since I might want to pursue a masters in computer science field, the grade in this course is relevant. I am confused as to whether a W along with a 9 grade in DSA would look worse on my transcript than a grade 7. Please give some advice regarding this.

Comment: How are you doing in comparison to other students? I know a few students who got into top universities (think Illinois, UCSD) despite a 7 in DSA (but in that class, 7 was still not worse than average).

Comment: 7 is the average grade, and like I said, I am currently a few marks below average and will need to cover that up in the end-semester exams.

Comment: I'd advise you to discuss this with professors from your university (those who write LoRs).

Answer (score 2):

This is hard to judge since graduate admissions seldom turn on a single data point, but some would question it. Your admission will depend on the judgement of individuals in some system, not the readers here.

But a more fundamental question is why you are doing mediocre in such a fundamental class. Dropping it might affect the option of taking more advanced courses next term and delaying your graduation, though I don't know your system. And if you are getting a poor (in your terms) grade for a correctable reason, I suggest you address that. Lack of time? Over extended? Lack of interest? Lazy? Unprepared? Cramming for exams? Inadequate notes? There are lots of possibilities, but it is just possible that a turn-around requires addressing the root cause.

Comment: I have gone over my courses for the next term and taking up this course again next semester will not delay my graduation. The source of my confusion right now is whether top universities would outright reject my application because of a W, even if I put in the work and do better next term. Also, if a 7 grade would harm my prospects at getting admission. I do realise I need to do some introspection and figure out the root cause before next term if I plan to redo this course.